# How to change netbeans script highlighting

Tags: php, netbeans, background, tags, highlight

I'm using Netbeans for PHP development and want to use a different theme besides the default. I really like the fact that the default changes the background between script tags but don't seem to see this feature in any of the other themes I've tried.

I know how to go into tools->options->fonts & colors but can't seem to find the setting that is responsible for this script highlighting.

The background between tags is a light green color (white on PHP insertion) and a light blue on the current line.

I'm in particular looking to use a dark theme, any recommendations appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use a dark theme on my NetBeans IDE (8.2) it's pretty easy to do

just go to Tools>PlugIns and search for Darcula (same as Jetbrains)

If you want you can also make your own theme by Tools> Options >Fonts & Colors> go in the tab "Highlight"

Comment: Which is what I think you are looking for

Comment: In the fonts & colors you can change anything from fonts, highlights, functions and even the IDE itself

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lucas, actually Darcula is the theme that I'm using but it doesn't highlight scripts differently than the rest of the page like the Netbeans default.  I could go in and change the script highlighting but am having trouble locating the setting responsible.

Comment: I once saw a post on stack exchange, you can check it in here: https://superuser.com/questions/516281/how-can-i-change-netbeans-highlight-color

Comment: Yes, I'd seen that comment in my research on how to change the setting.  Unfortunately, the version of NetBeans 8.2 (Build 201609300101) that my company is using doesn't have Java as one of the language selections under fonts & colors.  Could it be a setting in a system file since NetBeans is written in Java?